# How do I read an image from file for use with the `PyObjC Vision` framework?

Tags: python, core-graphics, vision, pyobjc

I am trying to detect and decode barcodes from a library of images. In most cases [`pyzbar`](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar) simply works (see code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972169/how-do-i-decode-partially-obscured-qr-codes)).

However, in some cases, my iPhone can decode the QR code but `zbar` fails. As I am on a mac, I can make use of the same `Vision` framework that the iPhone uses and there are even python wrappers to the macOS ObjC frameworks.

I tried using `Quartz.CGImageSourceCreateWithURL` but that returns a `None` no matter what I pass it.

```py
def read_image(path):
    imageSrc = Quartz.CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(path, None)
    image = Quartz.CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSrc, 0, None)
    return imageSrc, image

print(read_image(path))

Out: (None, None)
```

I have tried relative and absolute paths, I've tried internet URLs. Nothing.

Can someone help me get started with this?

Comment: I've never used the vision library just the google mlkit a bit. I don't have time to do a deep dive into the issue till at earliest next weekend (two labs to mark one to run tomorrow and a whole slew of other stuff on top of it.) Personally I'd make some simple test programs in Objective C and see if the approach you're taking works there and if not if using Objective C directly provides you more info for debugging, at the least you aught to be able to step inside the api and see what's happening in assembly code.

Comment: sorry forgot about this one, did you ever get this working?